# player/gazebo relative localization

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi i am the new user of player/gazebo and working on multiple robots which includes (relative localization, global mapping, planing) but this in not done with the help of player .... ?? Give any suggestion or either i use ros ??? @nate

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1731/player/gazebo-relative-localization/) by [Qubaish bhatti](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/254/qubaish-bhatti/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The player drivers in gazebo need some work, currently only position2d, camera, and I think laser are implemented.

I would recommend using ROS.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qubaish bhatti](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/254/qubaish-bhatti/) on 2013-03-20**:
is this work done in ros with gazebo or not ??? multi robot planing, and relative localization ??

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-09-19**:
ROS has localization and tools to support path planning. Multi-robot planning will require you to write your own code.